# Error in minifying babel transpiled ES2015 Code

Tags: javascript, webpack-2, babeljs, bundling-and-minification, transpiler

I am trying to minify babel preset ES2015 transpiled output but I was not successful in doing so. The transpiled code works, the minified version doesnt.

Here's an empty ES2015 JS class:

```
class TestApp {

}

export default TestApp;
```

Transpile the class using the babel cli.

```
$babel TestApp.js --out-file ../dist/TestApp.min.js
```

My .babelrc file.

```
{
        sourceMap: false,
        presets: ["es2015"],
        moduleRoot: '',
        moduleIds: true,
        plugins: [["transform-es2015-modules-umd", {
                "globals": {
                        "jquery": "jQuery"
                }
        }], "external-helpers"]
}
```

The output of TestApp.min.js

```
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define("/TestApp", ["exports"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(exports);
  } else {
    var mod = {
      exports: {}
    };
    factory(mod.exports);
    global.TestApp = mod.exports;
  }
})(this, function (exports) {
  "use strict";

  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });

  var TestApp = function TestApp() {
    babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this, TestApp);
  };

  exports.default = TestApp;
});
```

Checking the existence of TestApp in Chrome Inspector returns this output:

```
TestApp
{default: ƒ, __esModule: true}
default
:
ƒ TestApp()
__esModule
:
true
__proto__
:
Object
```

Now, moving onto the minification process. I am using webpack to transpile and minify TestApp.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        TestApp: __dirname + '/src/TestApp.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../../common/assets'),
        ]
    },
    module: {        
        rules: [            
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [ 'css-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions:{
              beautify: false,
              mangle: false,
              keep_classnames: true,
              keep_fnames: true
            }
        }
        ),  
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        })
    ]
}
```

Loading the minified version of TestApp in browser returns

```
TestApp
VM51511:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: TestApp is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: I simplified `.balerc` and `webpack.config.js` and removed all the details that aren't immediately relevant to your question (i.e. all the jQuery stuff). I also used babel-preset-env, as the es-2015-preset is outdated. And things worked as expected. I suggest you boil your question down to the bare minimum and post enough code here that others can easily reproduce your issue. Chances are you'll find the problem along the way.